# View not working as expected in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I have 3 columns in my view. 1st one shows the clients and second one shows the profiles created by the client and the third column shows the users linked to the profile. Everything works perfect logically except in view. When the list in client column is clicked it shows the profiles of the client that is clicked. When the profile is clicked it shows the users linked to profile in the 3rd column. But When the profile is clicked and the page is reloaded instead of showing the clicked profile name. It shows the profiles of the last client. Here are some pictures for better understanding. As you can see "John" is the user linked to the profile "VFX designer". But if you see in the profiles tab it shows backend Dev. which the profile of last client "test". I am attaching the pictures only for the better understanding. Here is my view code

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="clients_name">
 <ul>
   @foreach($client_details as $client)
   <a  href = "/candidates/{{$client->id}}"><li>{{$client->name}}</li></a>
    <li class="divider"></li>
   @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="profiles_name" style="min-height: 90vh; ">
  <ul>
  @foreach($user_profiles as $profile)
  <a href = "/candidates/{{$client->id}}/{{$profile->id}}"><li>{{$profile->profile_name}}</li></a>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  @endforeach           
  </ul>
```

#### image which shows client column

[image: image which shows client column]

#### Image that shows profiles after clicking client name

[image: Image that shows profiles after clicking client name]

#### Users linked to the profile of VFX designer

[image: Users linked to the profile of VFX designer]

As you can see in the 3rd image. The user john belongs to the profile VFX designer , after clicking it and page reloads and lists the last client profiles

Comment: Something to do with your URL params. In image 2, candidates is '2' whereas in image 3, candidate is '3'. Make sure the client `id` remains the same.

Comment: I have included the view code which takes the parameter, Can you see what mistake i am making there cause i am unable to locate it

Comment: in the 3rd image change url to `localhost:8000/candidates/2/22`. If the error disapears, then the error may be coming from `$user_profiles`. Also, try to `dd($user_profiles)` and see. Maybe post the result from `dd()` here.

Comment: It works perfectly after changing the url to `localhost:8000/candidates/2/22` I guess its in the view not with `$user_profiles`

Comment: There seems to be no error in the view. You simply echo `$client->id` and somehow, that `id` seems to change from 2 to 3. In the second loop try `<a href="./{{ $profile->id }}">` so it will only append the profile `id` to existing url `localhost:8000/candidates/2`. However, this will not solve the mystery surrounding the changing client `id`.

Comment: It doesn't append to the existing url but changes the whole url itself like 
`http://localhost:8000/candidates/22` instead of `http://localhost:8000/candidates/1/22`

Comment: ok make sure URL in screen 2 ends with a forward slash like this `localhost:8000/candidates/2/`. There is a final slash after 2.